# Lua pattern matching - Series of same character

Tags: lua, pattern-matching

Given s = "AAABBC", 
can we extract the first series of same character using pattern matching in Lua? "AAA" is what I am expecting to get.

Here's what I am thinking.

```
local s = "AAABBC"
print(s:match("([A-Z])%1*"))
```

But it returns nil.

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: In-pattern backreferences are not supported, so you need to use some external regex library, like PCRE.

Comment: What should be the output for `"DAAABBC"`?

Comment: Try `print(s:gsub("[A-Z]", "\0%0%0"):gsub("(.)%z%1", "%1"):match"%z.([A-Z]+)")`

Answer (score 1):

In-pattern backreferences in Lua patterns are not supported, you may want to use some external regex library that supports those contructs, like PCRE.

Egor Skriptunoff [suggests a work around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541679/lua-pattern-matching-series-of-same-character#comment84079802_48541679) that uses a null char as a temporary marker inside the string between groups of the same letters:

```
s:gsub("[A-Z]", "\0%0%0"):gsub("(.)%z%1", "%1"):match"%z.([A-Z]+)"
```

For `AAABBC` string, Egor's solution does the following:

- `gsub("[A-Z]", "\0%0%0")` - doubles each uppercase letter inserting a null before each sequence (`AAABBC` => `_AA_AA_AA_BB_BB_CC` where `_` repesents a null char) ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/LG8htG/1)
  )
- `gsub("(.)%z%1", "%1")` - replaces each char with a null followed with exactly the same char as before null with this same char (`_AA_AA_AA_BB_BB_CC` => `_AAAA_BBB_CC`) (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/LG8htG/2))
- `match"%z.([A-Z]+)")` matches the first occurrence of the null char, then any char, and then captures into Group 1 (and that is the value returned with `string.match`) any 1+ uppercase letters (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/LG8htG/3)).